# Which Stack Exchange site is best for stroke rehabilitation questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site is best for **stroke rehabilitation** questions like using Blender for Questions to Ask After a **Stroke**?

so one **sample question** is here :

My mother have had stroke for 8 years ago.

she could not walk without a walker and one person to move her left leg (stroking in right side of brain).

***So i want to know have could i help her for better walking by using new method or new instrument and knowing how much she could improve her walking?***

Answer (score 8):

You are running into a very common situation. The StackExchange sites are not good at handling a problem you are facing. They are fantastic at answering questions, and you can put the answers to several questions together, in order to solve your problem. Set aside for the moment the idea of stroke rehab. Imagine you want to go on holiday.

> Where should I go on holiday?

That's a terrible question. You can't go and ask that on Travel. Even if you add details about what you like and don't like, it's still not a good fit for a question and answer site. But if you start to get a little bit of an idea what you want, you can ask some really specific questions like how long it takes to get from Venice to  Milan by train, or what date skiing usually starts in the mountains around Vancouver, or whether there are places to leave your luggage for the day in Singapore. After you ask enough questions, you have planned your trip and solved your problem.

So, for the matter of stroke rehab, the two candidate sites are Heath and Fitness, but Fitness may not be quite as good a fit. But, and this is key, you can't ask "what exercises or techniques should this particular person do?" - that's personal medical advice. Instead, you will need to do some of the work yourself, and ask specific and crisp questions, like the sample travel questions above, that relate to your situation. I may not have this right, but something like:

- how common is it for stroke patients to regain function after several years?
- does physiotherapy and exercise help stroke patients gain strength?
- have there been changes in post-stroke treatments in the last few years that my doctor or physiotherapist may be unaware of?

(Come up with your own questions, of course - what specifically do you want to know that applies to her situation? The crisper the question the better. It should have a yes/no answer, or at least one that can be objectively correct, and especially on Health it's great if it's one that can be answered with links to studies and articles that are objective "proof" of the answer.)

This is way more work than "how can I help my mother?" but these questions are answerable. Someone who answers them may be contributing to the collection of knowledge you're working on that will solve your problem. After you get one answer, you may go and do some more research, or try something, or talk with one of your mother's care providers, and then you may come back with another question. That's great!

This is like the difference between what we sometimes call "plz send me teh codez" questions from people who have to write an application and don't know how, and questions that ask for help with one error message, or with using one particular function from one particular library, and over time, the person solves their problem, even though they never asked "please solve my problem" as a single question. I believe you can take a similar approach to learning more about the challenges your mother is facing and learning how to help her.